# How to do make the minimum XLM deposit upon account creation

Tags: stellar-core, accounts, xlm

How would one typically send the prerequisite 1 XLM to a new account upon creation?
Is this done by including the transfer from another account to the new account as part of the creation process?

Answer (score 3):

The `createAccount` operation takes a starting balance argument, and the account that creates the new account pays.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#create-account